# Unable to locate element within form tag despite using .switchTo().defaultContent()

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, iframe

So my html looks something like this:

```
<section>
  <div>
    <form>
      <div>here is username field</div>
      <div>here is password field</div>
      <div>
        <div>..
          <div>..
            <iframe>here is checkbox field</iframe> 
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div>here is login button</div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>resetpassword button</div>
 </section>
```

and here's what my selenium code looks like

```
const iframe = await this.getElementBySelector('#form-login > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > iframe');
await getCurrentDriver().switchTo().frame(iframe);
const checkBox = await this.getElementBySelector('#checkbox');
await checkBox.click();
await getCurrentDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
const loginSubmitButton = await this.getElementBySelector('#login');
await loginSubmitButton.click();
```

Now the problem is even after trying to switch to default content, I am unable to click login button (which is out of iframe but within the form, however, after switching to default content  if i try to locate reset password button (which is outside the form) it works great.
There's something trivial related to iframe/forms that i might be missing which making  my login button not to be clicked.. Any leads friends?

PS: The login button is disabled before we switch to the targeted frame, but when we do switchTo().defaultContent() its thinking that the button is still not enabled, on the UI the button appears enables though.

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait for the login button to become enabled? Please post a link to the page.

Comment: alternatively, you can try to submit the form by form.submit() method instead of clicking on login button. It may works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a wait statement before switching back to default content solved this for me. Thanks @JeffC for the answer.